# Kyma restart issue in local

Tags: windows, kubernetes, minikube, kyma

I have installed Kyma version 1.13.0 on Windows, it's working fine if I don't restart my machine or minikube. But when I restart minikube by following steps provided in the below link. Kyma is not working.

https://kyma-project.io/docs/latest/root/kyma#installation-install-kyma-locally-stop-and-restart-kyma-without-reinstalling

I need to reinstall kyma again to make it work.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: hi Subarna, did you resolved it? i'm struggling with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to what I get on my Windows machine.
This is the error that I get after restarting minikube.

*stderr:
error execution phase addon/coredns: unable to patch the CoreDNS deployment: Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher*

If you get same error, this has been reported as a bug.
https://github.com/kyma-project/cli/issues/455

My solution to this issue is to get the kyma working by issuing provision command twice, so give it a try.